# Footnote is not clickable and the PDF cannot be selected

Tags: hyperref, pdf, footnotes

Say in chapter 2, page 10 I create a foonote (by doing: `\footnote{bla bla....}`). When I reference it in Page 10 I get a clickable reference to that footnote. But, in page 12 when I reference this footnote using `\footnotemark[\value{footnote}]` , I get the number of the footnote correct, but this time its not clickable. How can I fix this?

I am using Windows 7, MikTEX 2.9 and TexMaker. The PDF that I create is OK. But I can't seem to copy any text from the PDF. When I click, a long vertical bar appears. I am using Adobe PDF for viewing.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: As I already mentioned in my answer to the cross-post at [LaTeX-Community.org](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=19822), the hyperref README says that the optional argument of `\footnotemark` is not supported, since such a reference is not clear, in general.

Comment: @StefanKottwitz Still being able to link to an already-defined footnote seems like a standard functionality to me which I'd expect to be supported by some package.

Comment: @StephanLehmke It was a general remark as I read the "official" statement in the README. Right, there may be a package which adds this functionality. Or let's write one. ;-)

Comment: @StefanKottwitz See code below ;-)

Comment: To the OP: Is my answer providing an acceptable solution?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `\footnotemark[...` is defined by `hyperref` to just typeset the number while a link is only created when `\footnotemark` is used without optional argument. Interestingly, in the latter case I was geting a link which lead nowhere.

It seems one must make an explicit mechanism for saving and restoring the link.

Try

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter

\newcommand\savefootnotemark[1]
{%
  \expandafter\edef\csname fnmark@#1\endcsname%
  {%
    \noexpand\do@fnmark
    {\number\c@footnote}{\unexpanded\expandafter{\Hy@footnote@currentHref}}%
  }%
}

\newcommand\footnoterefmark[1]
{%
  \csname fnmark@#1\endcsname%
}

\newcommand\do@fnmark[2]
{%
  \begingroup
    \c@footnote #1\relax
    \def\@thefnmark{\thefootnote}%
    \leavevmode
    \ifhmode\edef\@x@sf{\the\spacefactor}\nobreak\fi
    \hyper@linkstart{link}{#2}%
    \@makefnmark
    \hyper@linkend
    \ifhmode\spacefactor\@x@sf\fi
    \relax
  \endgroup
}  

\makeatother

\begin{document}

xxx

\clearpage

foo\footnote{bar}\savefootnotemark{fnone}.

\clearpage

baz\footnoterefmark{fnone}.\footnote{quux}\savefootnotemark{fntwo}

\clearpage

test1\footnoterefmark{fntwo},test2\footnoterefmark{fnone}.

\end{document}
```

One should think this is such a common request it must have been done in some package already.